# Is there a mistake in this passage about lower semi-continuity?

Tags: continuity, semicontinuous-functions

Im reading a paper, where I find this problem:

Let $f, g$ two function such that from a Banach space $\mathbb R$ into itself:

- $f$ is continuous, and $g$ is lower  [semi-continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity#:%7E:text=A%20function%20f%20%3A%20Rn,the%20Scott%20topology%20on%20R.);
- $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ which converges to x.
- $f(x_n)\leq f(x_n)-g(x_n),\:\forall n\in \mathbb N$.

In the passage, the author writes:

> Taking the limsup in the above inequality, we have:
> $$\begin{matrix}
> \limsup _{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) &\leq &\limsup _{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)-\liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty} g(x_n)\\ 
> \text{ Then }\\
> f(x) &\leq &f(x)-g(x)
> \end{matrix}$$

I think that ther is something wrong about this, any help!

Comment: Why do you think there is something wrong?

Comment: I think he should use the liminf $$
\liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty} \theta\left(\omega\left(C_{n+1}\right)\right) \leq \liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty} \theta\left(\omega\left(C_{n}\right)\right)-\liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty} \phi\left(\theta\left(\omega\left(C_{n}\right)\right)\right)
$$ and then Therefore,
$$
\theta(r) \leq \theta(r)-\phi(\theta(r))
$$

Comment: When  a sequence is convergent there is no difference between $\lim$, $\lim \inf$ and $\lim\sup$. Since $f$ is continuous, $(f(x_n)$ converges. Also it is not true that $\lim \inf (a_n-b_n) \leq \lim \inf a_n -\lim \inf b_n$.